# Problem with % and / in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with the % and / characters in Java regex. The following example will illustrate my issue:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]*[/%]$");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("a%/");
System.out.println(m.find());
```

It prints "false" when I expect it to be "true". The % and / sign shouldn't have to be escaped but even if I do it still dosn't work.

So my question is simply why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^[a-z]*[/%]$` matches zero or more lower case letters followed by one character which can be either `/` or `%` - to allow multiple characters, use

```
^[a-z]*[/%]+$
```

`+` stands for one or more; use `*` for zero or more.

If you didn't have `$` at the end of the regex, it would have matched `a%` in the string`a%/`.

`$` matches end of line.

Comment: Oh, sometime you just make very stupid mistakes. I though the + or * sign was before not after. I just didn't see it when I looked at other examples either... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression says "zero or more lower case letters then `/` **or** `%` then the end of the string".

The string matches until it gets a `/` when it was looking for the end of the string.

You probably want to remove the square brackets to say "`/` then `%`"

Answer (score 0):

You just check for *one* of the `[%/]` characters to appear, not the possibility of having both.

Try `[%/]?` (or +, *, depending what you want)